# Requests not compatible with non-"https://" schemas

Tags: python, https, python-requests, schema

I am trying to make a program that takes in a zoom meeting id and password, builds a link based on the schema given in the [zoom docs](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/guides/client-url-schemes) like this :

```
zoommtg://zoom.us/join?confno=12345&pwd=xxxx
```

And this DOES work in the browser (chrome at least AND using a valid zoom id and password...) and a dialog box pops up to confirm to join the meeting. But when I pop it into `requests.get(r"zoommtg://zoom.us/join?confno=12345&pwd=xxxx")` , it gives the following error

```
 raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'zoommtg://zoom.us/join?confno=12345&pwd=xxxxx'
```

Any way to fix this / is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "zoommtg" is a custom protocol that the Zoom client sets up in your operating system which when called from a webbrowser will forward those parameters into the Zoom client. You can't really "get" the URL, it is not a web page (those have protocol http/https).
If what you want is to launch the Zoom client, you could instead launch it via (on Windows):

```
os.startfile(url)
```